# JSON menu alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Based on [this tutorial](http://www.jqwidgets.com/building-menu-from-json/) i made JSON menu. And now items sorted by id, but i need sort them alphabetically and can't understand how to do that. Not sure if `array.sort();` will help in my case

Here is JS code:

```
var builddata = function () {
  var source = [];
  var items = [];

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    var label = item["text"];
    var parentid = item["parentid"];
    var id = item["id"];
    if (items[parentid]) {
        var item = { parentid: parentid, label: label, item: item };
        if (!items[parentid].items) {
            items[parentid].items = [];
        }
        items[parentid].items[items[parentid].items.length] = item;
        items[id] = item;
      }
      else {
        items[id] = { parentid: parentid, label: label, item: item };
        source[id] = items[id];
      }
    }
   return source;
   }
var source = builddata();
var buildUL = function (parent, items) {
  $.each(items, function () {
    if (this.label) {
        var li = $("<li>" + this.label + "</li>");
        li.appendTo(parent);           
        if (this.items && this.items.length > 0) {
            var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
            ul.appendTo(li);
            buildUL(ul, this.items);
        }
    }
  });
 }
 var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
 ul.appendTo("#jqxMenu");
 buildUL(ul, source);
```

HTML:

```
 <div id='jqxMenu'>     
 </div>
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/97U5E/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  source.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.text < b.text) return -1;
    if(a.text > b.text) return 1;
    return 0;
  })
```

...is the basis. However, recursive implementation is needed in this case I suppose.

Here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4Cap/1/)

Comment: Just sorting alphabetically by text will break the grouping of the sub headings.

Comment: it would be useful if you could add some lines to explain your code

Comment: It was so ridiculously obvious that I thought it is needed not to explain. However, OP managed to use it in wrong place. I've added jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Try sort the `source` u return

```
return source.sort();
```

See: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/97U5E/1/)